# Apache2 Ubuntu Server Module not found 'django'

Tags: django, apache, server, wsgi

I have been trying to move a django project on my Linode server into production.  After trying to use Apache and wsgi by following an online tutorial by Corey Schafer, I have encountered the following problem.  I cannot for the life of my understand why this is happening, and have included error logs, my wsgi.py and my .conf file below.

```
[Tue Sep 29 23:20:35.753537 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 143850:tid 140318623627008] [remote 90.214.108.58:50288]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Sep 29 23:20:35.753556 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 143850:tid 140318623627008] [remote 90.214.108.58:50288] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Tue Sep 29 23:28:18.507904 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 143849:tid 140318652456000] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Sep 29 23:28:18.590367 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 143989:tid 139664706964544] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 29 23:28:18.590439 2020] [core:notice] [pid 143989:tid 139664706964544] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Sep 29 23:28:24.089588 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 143990:tid 139664678135552] [remote 90.214.108.58:50411] mod_wsgi (pid=143990): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/myname/projects/uw5-backend/u>
[Tue Sep 29 23:28:24.089643 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 143990:tid 139664678135552] [remote 90.214.108.58:50411] mod_wsgi (pid=143990): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/myname/projects/uw5-b>
[Tue Sep 29 23:28:24.095135 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 143990:tid 139664678135552] [remote 90.214.108.58:50411] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Sep 29 23:28:24.095172 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 143990:tid 139664678135552] [remote 90.214.108.58:50411]   File "/home/myname/projects/uw5-backend/uw5tables/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Tue Sep 29 23:28:24.095178 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 143990:tid 139664678135552] [remote 90.214.108.58:50411]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Sep 29 23:28:24.095195 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 143990:tid 139664678135552] [remote 90.214.108.58:50411] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

***wsgi.py***

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# add the hellodjango project path into the sys.path
sys.path.append('home/myname/projects/uw5-backend')

# add the virtualenv site-packages path to the sys.path
sys.path.append('home/myname/projects/uw5-backend/venv2/bin')

# poiting to the project settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'uw5tables.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

***.conf***

```
     <Directory /home/myname/projects/uw5-backend/uw5tables>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myname/projects/uw5-backend/uw5tables/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/myname/projects/uw5-backend python-home=/home/myname/projects/uw5-backend/venv2
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app
</VirtualHost>
```